# How to restore an IE in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, internet-explorer

It's really strange, I do not have IE on my machine. It's not `I lost my shortcut` question, I really don't have it.

I just don't have it in my `system32` folder. I want to test some polyfills, that are not working in edge, but should work in IE. But I can't, becuase it's missing.

Any idea how to restore it?[image]

Comment: My iexplore.exe is located in `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer` on Windows 10

Comment: Tnx, however, I have only `iediagcmd`, `ieinstal` and `ielowutil` there (and several folders and dlls)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click Start, click Command Prompt (Admin). Type:

`sfc /scanfile="c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"`

See if that restores it. Let's know.

Also, check if IE is enabled in Optional Features.

Press WinKey + R, and type `optionalfeatures.exe`
Enable the checkbox for Internet Explorer, and click OK.

If it's already enabled, uncheck it, click OK. Repeat the steps and enable the checkbox again, and click OK.

Comment: Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.

Comment: Thank you, problem was in disabled IE feature. I could really find it out myself, but anyway I didn't encounter any related information about it except *how to recover missing IE shortcut*, so I think it would be helpful for community.

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 6):

Internet Explorer, iexplore.exe, will be located in `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer`. If it does not appear there, Internet Explorer has been turned off in Windows Features.

To enable it, search for Windows Features and select **Turn Windows features on or off**.

[image: Windows Features]

Then check the box next to **Internet Explorer 11**.

[image: Internet Explorer 11]

You will need to **restart** the computer to apply these changes.

Source: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27095-internet-explorer-install-uninstall-windows-10-a.html

Comment: I upvote you too, becuase you both are right. Thank you for help.